# Freeing the stack

Tags: c, memory-management

So I know that a call `free()` on a variable allocated in the stack would cause an invalid pointer error.

In a `malloc`ed pointer, `malloc()` allocates 8 bytes before the actual pointer to leave information about its size. So I was wondering if I had made a `long` before a struct and then called free on that struct if it would be possible to free the struct (of course this is going off the assumption that the allocation of those 8 bytes is the only thing extra that `malloc` does).

I guess my final question would be if there is any real difference between stack variable allocation and heap allocation (in terms of the backend calls to the kernel).

Comment: _allocates 8 bytes before the actual pointer to leave information about its size._ - You are making an assumption on its implementation

Comment: @Ed Heal the glibc implementation does that with malloc

Comment: It does not have to. What about other implementations of `malloc`. Future implementations of `glibc` may not do this

Comment: @AndreiTumbar not really sure what your question is. If you want to trick `free` to think pointer you passed to it was previously `malloc`d, - well, that's very likely to be possible, just look how your libc checks given pointer. But at best case it will corrupt malloc heap. What's the point?

Comment: @keltar I would never actually use this I was just pondering the possibility because I still don't fully understand how the stack is really handled.

Comment: @AndreiTumbar `free` is not allmightly; it is your responsibility to pass it pointer that was previously `malloc`d. If you don't, things will go bad. As for stack, you don't need to do anything about it. Once function returns, stack resets to what it was before calling said function.

Comment: @keltar That is a very "blackbox" way of looking at this. It is nice to understand the inner workings of things because then it is easier to catch bugs.

Comment: @AndreiTumbar no it really isn't. Stack is just flat buffer, and CPU with stack support have register that points to current 'top'. Compiler generates modifications of that 'top' for you. That is why it is so cheap - it is always there, and 'freeing' it is always one operation per function, no matter how much of stack space you acltually used.

Comment: @keltar So are you saying that variables allocated in the stack may or may not be registers depending on the implementation, the compiler, and the CPU?

Comment: ... And the optimisation and the OS and their various versions

Comment: @AndreiTumbar I have no idea what you're talking about. If compiler decided to use register for variable storage - it is clearly not "on the stack". But yes, if we're talking about 'automatic storage' - then compiler decides where to put it, depending on target architecture and a lot of other factors (including programmer's hints, like `register` keyword). I don't think C standard mentions stack at all, it is just very common approach.

Answer (score 3):

Some C implementations might use data before the allocated space to help them manage the space. Some do not. Some do that for allocations of certain sizes and not others. If they do it, it might be eight bytes, or it might be some other amount. You should not rely on any behavior in this regard.

When you declare a `long` object and a `struct` of some sort in a block, the compiler might or might not put them next to each other on the stack. It might put the `long` before the `struct` or vice-versa, or, because it optimizes your program, it might keep the `long` in a register and never put it on the stack at all, and it might do other things. In some `C` implementations, a `long` is eight bytes. In some, it is not. There is no good way for you to ensure two separate objects are put in adjacent memory. (You can make them not separate by putting them in a larger struct.)

Even if you are able to cobble together a `long` followed by a `struct`, how would you know what value to put into the `long`? Did the C implementation put the length of the allocation in there? Or is it a pointer to another block? Or to some other part of the database the C implementation uses to track allocated memory? If `malloc` and `free` are using memory just before the allocated space, that memory is not empty. It needs to have some value in it, and you do not know what that is.

If you get lucky, passing the address of the `struct` to `free` might not crash your program right away. But then you have freed a part of the stack, in some sense. When you call `malloc` again, the pointer you get back might be for that memory, and then your program presumably will write to that space. Then what happens when your program calls other routines, causing the stack to grow into that space? You will have overlapping uses of the same memory. Some of your data will be stomping over other data, and your program will not work.

Yes, there are differences between memory allocated on the stack and memory allocated from the heap. This is outside of the model that C presents to your program. However, in systems where processes have stack and heap, they are generally in different places in the memory of your process. In particular, the stack memory must remain available for use as the stack grows and shrinks. You cannot mix it with the heap without breaking things.

It is good to ask questions about what happens when you try various things. However, modern implementations of `malloc` and `free` are quite complicated, and you pretty much have to accept them as a service that you cannot peer into easily. Instead, to help you learn, you might think about this:

- How would you write your own `malloc` and `free`?
- Write some code that allocates a large amount of memory using `malloc`, say a megabyte, and write two routines called `MyMalloc` and `MyFree` that work like `malloc` and `free`, except they use the memory you allocated. When `MyMalloc` is called, it will carve out a chunk of the memory. When `MyFree` is called, it will return the chunk to make it available again.
- Write some experimental code that somewhat randomly calls `MyMalloc` with various sizes and `MyFree`, in somewhat random orders.
- How can you make all of this work? How do you divide the megabyte into chunks? How do you remember which chunks are allocated and which are free? When somebody calls `MyFree`, how do you know how much they are giving back? When neighboring chunks are returned with `MyFree`, how do you put them back together into bigger pieces again?

Answer (score 0):

I think your real question is how does the stack work.

The stack is one big memory block allocated when your program starts. There is a pointer to the top of the stack. The name is suggestive: think of a stack of magazines.

When a function is called, the parameters are placed on top of the stack. The function itself then places its local variables on top of that. When the function exits, the stack pointer is simply moved back to where it was before the function was called. This frees all the local variables and input arguments used by the function.

The heap manager has nothing to do with this block of memory. Tricking `free` to put some of the stack in the heap manager’s memory is going to wreak havoc on your program. The memory would likely be used again as you call other functions, and used simultaneously if you `malloc` memory, leading to data corruption at best, and stack corruption (read crash) at worst.

Answer (score 0):

When you speak of memory being allocated on the stack, you have to understand that in most implementations, the stack is allocted in a block -- variables are not allocated individually or separately.

```
                     +-+ +--------------------------------------------------+
                     |   | Stack frame data section; local variables and    |
                     |   |                                                  |
                     |   | function arguments in order determined by the    |
                     |   |                                                  |
                     |   | calling convention of the target platform        |
Stack frame for      |   |                                                  |
function call;   +---+   | (size is implementation dependent)               |
block allocated      |   |                                                  |
                     |   |                                                  |
                     |   +--------------------------------------------------+
                     |   |Instruction pointer (return address)              |
                     |   +--------------------------------------------------+
                     |   |Space for return value (if not in a CPU register) |
                     +-+ +--------------------------------------------------+
                         |                                                  |
                         |                                                  |
                         |                                                  |
                         |     (stack frame of previously called function)  |
                         |                                                  |
                         |                                                  |
                         +--------------------------------------------------+
```

Each function call is allocated its own stack frame, with the required size to hold the return value (if necessary), the instruction pointer of the return address, and all of the local variables and function arguments. So while memory for the stack frame is allocated, it's not allocated with respect to any individual variable -- only in regard to the sum of the individual sizes.